# HandShake Exception while connecting through rest with certificate

Tags: java, web-services, rest, ssl, curl

On server I've got a certificate which I am using to connect to other webservice. 
Certificate is correctly installed on server, because when I am using curl to make a request, everything works fine. The problem is when I am using rest request through my webservice in Spring.
I've got exception:

```
handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
```

I was trying changing tls protocols and it didn't help.

What may cause the problem?
There is a code of a debugger:

```
    https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 120
https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, received EOFException: error
https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, called closeSocket()
https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, called close()
https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-4, called closeInternal(true)
```

Comment: You need to check the server side logs to see what the problem is.

Comment: How I can check this logs ?

Comment: Start by looking at the documentation to find out where they are.  It will depend on what you are running your webservice on.